# boot2docker is autoupgrading

Tags: docker, boot2docker

i installed https://github.com/docker/toolbox/releases/download/v1.9.1j/DockerToolbox-1.9.1j.exe  as i need docker 1.9.
On starting the dockertools it detected that my boot2iso is old and updated the same to latest.For sure i had unchecked the auto upgrade option during installation "upgrade boot2docker VM"
I do not want to upgrade.Please help

```
Running pre-create checks... (default) Default Boot2Docker ISO is out-of-date, downloading the latest release ... (default) Latest release for github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker is v1.10.2 (default) Downloading C:\Users\akathaku\.docker\machine\cache\boot2docker.iso fr om github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/download/v1.10.2/… ker.iso...
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem recently and solved it by running the following:

~$ `docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-boot2docker-url=https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/download/v1.9.1/boot2docker.iso default`

For note, using this method currently suffers from the following issue: https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/2195

I hope it helps!